# What's wrong with this Linked List implementation?

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, linked-list

> Design your implementation of the linked list. You can choose to use the singly linked list or the doubly linked list. A node in a singly linked list should have two attributes: val and next. val is the value of the current node, and next is a pointer/reference to the next node. If you want to use the doubly linked list, you will need one more attribute prev to indicate the previous node in the linked list. Assume all nodes in the linked list are 0-indexed.

```
class MyLinkedList {
public:
    /** Initialize your data structure here. */
     struct node{
           int val;
           struct node* next;
       }*first;
    MyLinkedList() {
      first=NULL;
    }
    
    /** Get the value of the index-th node in the linked list. If the index is invalid, return -1. */
    int get(int index) {
       
        node* it=first;
        int i;
        for(i=0;i<index-1;i++)
        {
            
            it=it->next;
        
        }
        return it->val;
    }
    
    /** Add a node of value val before the first element of the linked list. After the insertion, the new node will be the first node of the linked list. */
    void addAtHead(int val) {
     node* p=new node;
     p->val=val;
     p->next=first;
     first=p;
    }
    
    /** Append a node of value val to the last element of the linked list. */
    void addAtTail(int val) {
       node* p=new node;
        p->val=val;
        p->next=NULL;
        node* it=first;
        while(it->next!=NULL)
        {
            it=it->next;
        }
        it->next=p;
    }
    
    /** Add a node of value val before the index-th node in the linked list. If index equals to the length of linked list, the node will be appended to the end of linked list. If index is greater than the length, the node will not be inserted. */
    void addAtIndex(int index, int val) {
        int i;
        node* it=first;
        node* prev=NULL;
        node* p=new node;
        p->val=val;
        for(i=0;i<index-1;i++)
        {
            prev=it;
            it=it->next;
        
        }
        prev->next=p;
        p->next=it;
        
    }
    
    /** Delete the index-th node in the linked list, if the index is valid. */
    void deleteAtIndex(int index) {
        int i;
        node* it=first;
        node* prev=NULL;
        for(i=0;i<index-1;i++)
        {
            prev=it;
            it=it->next;
        
        }
        prev->next=it->next;
        delete it;
    }
};
```

Function expressions have the following meanings,

> get(index) : Get the value of the index-th node in the linked list. If the index is invalid, return -1.

> addAtHead(val) : Add a node of value val before the first element of the linked list. After the insertion, the new node will be the first node of the linked list.

> addAtTail(val) : Append a node of value val to the last element of the linked list.

> addAtIndex(index, val) : Add a node of value val before the index-th node in the linked list. If index equals to the length of linked list, the node will be appended to the end of linked list. If index is greater than the length, the node will not be inserted.

> deleteAtIndex(index) : Delete the index-th node in the linked list, if the index is valid.

Comment: *What's wrong with this Linked List implementation?* -- Is there anything wrong with it?  If there is something wrong, you should state that in your question as to what's wrong.

Comment: One thing is wrong for sure: It's missing a destructor.

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Also, consider extracting a [mcve] in order to make your question more specific.

Comment: What makes you think that something is wrong?

Comment: Deleting the first element requires a special case.

Comment: I am doing Leetcode so I know from there, Thanks for the tip btw @molbdnilo.

Comment: In the three methods `get()`, `addAtIndex()` and `deleteAtIndex()`, the line `for(i=0;i<index-1;i++)` should be `for(i=0;i<index;i++)` instead.

Comment: It's violating the [Rule of Three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are what's wrong:

- `get()` doesn't check if the index is invalid.
- `addAtTail()` cannot handle empty list well.
- `addAtIndex()` cannot handle insertion to before 0-th node (head) well.
- `addAtIndex()` cannot handle index greater than the length well.
- `deleteAtIndex()` cannot handle deletion of 0-th node (head) well.
- `deleteAtIndex()` donesn't check if the index is valid.

Comment: It'll also leak when it's being destroyed.

Comment: I implemented it using vector and it worked, will tweak this one with the tips i got.